# Rails 4+: only select specific columns from an included association

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, query-optimization

I have a `user` model that belongs to to an `account` (pretty standard).  On every request, I need to retrieve the `current_user` but I also want to return the `account` to reduce DB queries:

```
# ApplicationController
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.includes(:account).find_by(auth_token: cookies[:auth_token])
end

def current_account
  @current_account ||= current_user.account
end
```

This works just fine. However, the `account` record has a lot of extra text data that I don't always want to return.  A more permanent solution would be to move those extra fields to a new table called `account_details` and have a one-to-one between an `account` and `account_details`.

However, I need a shorter-term solution that will provide some optimizations until I can refactor that (perfection is an iterative process!).

I want to return ALL columns from the `current_user`, but I only want to select a few columns from the `current_account`.

I tried this and I didn't work:

```
@current_user ||= User.includes(:account).references(:account).select("users.*, account.id, account.uuid").find_by(auth_token: cookies[:auth_token])
```

When I look at `@current_user.account` it still displays all the columns with their values and I only wanted the `id, uuid` columns.

I couldn't find any clear syntax on using `select(...)` with `includes(:association)`; is this something that's possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an extra association in your **User** model.

```
belongs_to :account_columns, -> { select(:id, :uuid) }, class_name: 'Accoun'
```

This association should be used in your query.

```
User.includes(:account_columns)
```

This is because Rails don't have the facility to pass the options for include query.

Also consider using **join** instead **includes** in your query, as it also caters your need.

```
User.joins(:accounts).select("accounts_ids, accounts.uuid")
```